# CASCADE DELETE per statement

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint, delete, cascade

Can I execute something like this in Postgresql, that is, execute `CASCADE DELETE` for just *one* statement?

```
DELETE CASCADE FROM foo WHERE bar = 'baz';
```

My goal is to delete not just the selected record(s) from table `foo`, but **all the records in all the tables** where `foo.id` column is used as a foreign key, **without** adding the constraint for the **entire** table `foo`: `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

**Related:**

- [postgresql - CASCADE DELETE just once - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129265/cascade-delete-just-once) - a similar question was asked in 2008. I wonder if anything has changed since then.
- [Deleting a row in one table should also delete the corresponding rows in another table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/332667/192715) - I want to avoid this, since it `ALTER`s the entire table, and affects all the `DELETE` statements. I want to do something like this, but **on a per statement basis**.
- [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 16: 5.4. Constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) - could not find an answer in the docs.
- [Is it a good or bad idea to use "ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE" for foreign keys? Why does this mechanism exist at all?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/254605/192715) - The pros and cons of `ON DELETE CASCADE` are discussed in the answers in this Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically delete all dependent rows; you will have to delete them before you delete the referenced row.

Answer (score 1):

1. ALTER and UPDATE each child table to have a copy of the field bar from its parent record in foo.
2. DELETE all rows in each child table where bar = 'baz'.
3. Clean up by ALTER DROP COLUMN on the new fields which are no longer needed.
4. Finally, DELETE the parent table's rows where bar = 'baz'.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify what SQL commands are used. This answer requires that you temporarily ALTER the child tables.